# How Do I Determine the Security Account that IIS Uses to Run My Web Site?

Tags: security, iis, authentication

I'm using silverlight on IIS 7 and i created a folder "Logs" where i want to write (in a txt file) all the error that occured.

To solve the problem by now i've set the security rights of that folder to everyone, but i want to give the rights only to user(s) who will write into the log.
(That would be the user that is running IIS)

So my questions:
- How Do I Determine the Security Account that IIS Uses to Run My Web Site?
- Will that user be the same if i'm running my website under Windows Authentication? (now it's running under Anonymous authentication)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to advanced settings and look at the application pool being used by your web app. Then go into the application pools section of IIS admin and go to advanced settings of the relevant app pool. You should see the identity which is being used in there somewhere.